# is there user defined flags i can set/check in ZwCreateFile/InitializeObjectAttributes inside file system driver?

Tags: c, windows, winapi, device-driver

I am developing file system driver under Windows and i need to check file attributes of every accessed file. To do this i need to do additional ZwCreateFile for each file, but again it returns to my dispatch routine.

What flags i can set with InitializeObjectAttributes() or ZwCreateFile() so i can check it later so my filter can bypass such file access?

Thank you.

Comment: you already asked this question and appear to have copied the answer from that other question. Why?

Comment: @David, just new question meets all rules for questions better than this. i will close this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved, try IoCreateFileSpecifyDeviceObjectHint, IoCreateFileEx or FtlCreateFile.